# How do make my application names in FirefoxOS appear in two lines in home screen?

Tags: firefox-os

I understand that FirefoxOS truncates (hides) the name of an application if it is too long. Is there a way I can specify in my app manifest or anywhere to show it the full name? Atleast two rows? Or make them shrink (reduce size) automatically(like what happens in Google Now Launcher in android)?

Anyway to show full name?
Or renaming my app to something short, but not so meaningful is the only option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this in any Firefox OS version available (up until 2.1, who knows what happens). So a shorter name is the only way for now.

Comment: I also came to that conclusion and renamed my app to a much shorter and less user friendly name